# Genus of a modular curve mod p

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modular-forms

I am reading a paper that states the following without reference:

The modular curve $X_0(\mathcal{l})/p$, $l \neq p$ has genus $[\mathcal{l}/12]$.

Does anyone know where this comes from? I am finding a ton of references that study the genus of the modular curve before reduction but nothing similar to what I am seeing here.

Comment: Is $\ell \ne p$ here? Then $X_0(\ell)$ is smooth over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, and the genus of the special fibre of a smooth $\mathbf{Z}_p$-scheme is the same as that of the generic fibre.

Comment: yes $l \neq p$, thanks.